# VBA Updating / Modifying Array in a Multi-nested Dictionary

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, dictionary, nested

the below is the full VBA code. I have created a multi-nested dictionary with the keys structure of `team` > `member` > `mth` . The values will be stored as an array so that I can access the values using `mydict(team)(member)(mth)(0 or 1)`.

however when I'm updating the arrays by looping through dictionary keys and declaring a temporary array for modifying the elements of arrays. It doesnt go to the correct way.

Full VBA Code

```
Sub test()

Dim mydict1 As New Scripting.Dictionary
Dim mydict2 As New Scripting.Dictionary
Dim mydict3 As New Scripting.Dictionary
Dim mydict4 As New Scripting.Dictionary

For Each mth In Array(1, 2)
    mydict3.Add mth, Array("NA", "NA")
Next mth

For Each member In Array(11, 22, 33)
    mydict4.Add member, mydict3
Next member

For Each team In Array(1, 2)
mydict1.Add team, mydict4
Next team

i = 1

For Each team In mydict1.Keys()
    For Each member In mydict1(team).Keys()
        For Each mth In mydict1(team)(member).Keys()

                Dim tmparr As Variant

                tmparr = mydict1(team)(member)(mth)
                tmparr(0) = i
                mydict1(team)(member)(mth) = tmparr
                Debug.Print mth & "---" & team & "---" & member & "---" & Join(mydict1(team)(member)(mth), "---")
                i = i + 1
            
        Next mth
    Next member
Next team


Debug.Print "================================================='"

For Each team In mydict1.Keys()
    For Each member In mydict1(team).Keys()
        For Each mth In mydict1(team)(member).Keys()
                Debug.Print mth & "---" & team & "---" & member & "---" & Join(mydict1(team)(member)(mth), "---")
        Next mth
    Next member
Next team

End Sub
```

Output

```
1---1---11---11---NA
2---1---11---12---NA
1---1---22---11---NA
2---1---22---12---NA
1---1---33---11---NA
2---1---33---12---NA
1---2---11---11---NA
2---2---11---12---NA
1---2---22---11---NA
2---2---22---12---NA
1---2---33---11---NA
2---2---33---12---NA
```

Expected output

```
1---1---11---1---NA
2---1---11---2---NA
1---1---22---3---NA
2---1---22---4---NA
1---1---33---5---NA
2---1---33---6---NA
1---2---11---7---NA
2---2---11---8---NA
1---2---22---9---NA
2---2---22---10---NA
1---2---33---11---NA
2---2---33---12---NA
```

Comment: You are using and updating the same objects all along the program. Adding an object to a dictionary multiple times does not create copies of the object

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to distinguish between arrays and objects in VBA. Unlike other programming languages, VBA doesn't handle **arrays** as objects.

That means if you write

```
mydict3.Add mth, Array("NA", "NA")
```

VBA will first create an array with 2 string variables ("NA", "NA"), and then *create a copy* of that array when you assign it as value to a dictionary. Similarly, when you read the array out of the dictionary, VBA will *copy* the array to the variable `tmpArr`. If you then modify that array, you will need to write it back to the dictionary entry (which again will create a copy). You do this already:

```
 tmparr = mydict1(team)(member)(mth)    ' Copy the array to tmp variable
 tmparr(0) = i                          ' Modify the array
 mydict1(team)(member)(mth) = tmparr    ' Write the modification back to the dict
```

If you would write `mydict1(team)(member)(mth)(0) = i`, the array that is stored in the dictionary wouldn't be modified because also here first a copy is created. This leads often to confusion and there are several questions around that here on SO.

**Objects** are different. When you write

```
mydict4.Add member, mydict3
```

the value that is stored is the *reference* to the dictionary `myDict3`. All entries in `myDict4` will point to the exact same object `myDict3`, and if you modify `myDict3`, it will affect *all* entries of `myDict4`.

So what you have to do is to create a new Dictionary object for `myDict3` when filling `myDict4`, and you will need to create a new Dictionary object for `myDict4` when filling up `myDict1`.

Have a look to the following code. As I found your naming quite confusing, I took the freedom to rename the dictionary objects:

```
Dim teamDict As Scripting.Dictionary
Dim mthDict As Scripting.Dictionary
Dim memberDict As Scripting.Dictionary

Set teamDict = New Dictionary
Dim team
For Each team In Array(1, 2)
    Set memberDict = New Dictionary
    Dim member
    For Each member In Array(11, 22, 33)
        Set mthDict = New Dictionary
        Dim mth
        For Each mth In Array(1, 2)
            mthDict.Add mth, Array("NA", "NA")
        Next mth
        memberDict.Add member, mthDict
    Next member
    teamDict.Add team, memberDict
Next team
```

Comment: Thomas, you translate dry matter into really helpful *fun* - where can you actually get such good coffee machines as supporting tool?